# CHMOD usage to add read only permission to an existing directory structure

Tags: chmod

Hello all and Good day!

I'm trying to figure out how to add read only permissions to a directory and all child directories to (1) specific user. I attempted, not thinking correctly the following command: chmod -R 005 /dir/ would work, but as I quickly discovered this removed all the previous permissions from the directory/file to only read and execute, not something I wanted.

My question is, I've added a new user to a system, and want them to have read only access to a directory/child directories/files below this without modifying existing permissions in place. NOTE: Some child directories/files have "rwx" for other currently in place.

I need to grant read only access for this (1)user to the directory and all child directories/files without modifying/removing the "rwx" for some directories/files, potentially used or allowed for other single users. Is this even possible?

Thanks for any assistance that can be provided.

Comment: The exact syntax will probably depend on the version of your operating system, and which command shell you use, but `+r` is a typical permission you can add. Tell us what your OS and shell are, and also what the manual entry for chmod offers you.

Comment: `chmod -R o+rX /dir/`, perhaps? That will add read permission to everything, and execute permission for things that already have one of the other execute bits set (may be more permissive than you want, but you need to have the execute bits on for directories in order to `cd` into them - an alternative would be `find /dir/ -type d -exec chmod o+rX {} +` to handle directories, followed by `chmod -R o+r /dir/`)...

Comment: Thank you for  your responses, as noted however, when I did "chmod -R  005" /folder/ it made every folder and file under /folder/ ------r-x which is not what I wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. As noted, when I issued the commmand as noted here: chmod -R 005 /folder/ it changed all child directories and files to the permissions ------r-x which is not what I wanted.As noted some child directories and even some files have DRWXRWXRWX on them now. Is there a way to have only 1 user have RX on child directories and files without removing the existing permissions set world rwx? RHEL5.5

Comment: @user309837 You should probably read through `man chmod`, especially the parts covering the `[ugoa]*([-+=]([rwxXst]*|[ugo]))+` syntax... You can easily set specific permissions for the owner, group, everyone else, or everyone with that syntax, instead of having to worry about the octal numbers...

Comment: Thank you all, I basically did every directory and file by hand instead, but thanks for the attempts.